# Delay execution of Python script after system start up

Tags: python, boot

I've got a Python script that I need to run upon start up and problem
is that it throws an error saying "no module named xyz". I'm using external library which I installed using pip3. The script works just fine on its own
but I get aforementioned error when I want to run it right after boot.

What should I do ? I tried to delay importing the library with time.sleep(10) in case third-party libraries need few more seconds to load up after boot, but that didn't have desired effect.

I run the script on Raspberry Pi with Debian-based os called Raspbian. I configured execution upon start up by adding this `sudo python3 script.py` into /etc/profile file.

Comment: For some reason your python does not see that library. Are you using conda?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with timing.

Comment: Is the external library installed in a virtual environment, perhaps, and you run the script at start-up without using the virtual environment?

Comment: @jason m   No, I'm not familiar with that library.

Comment: Please add the details - how you run your script on startup. Include OS, the way you made it run on startup, how you installed the modules. My guess is that you run it from cron job; in that case, the `$PATH` and other environment variables are empty.

Comment: @zmbq   No, I don't find running this script in virtualenv necessary.

Comment: @VictorSergienko  I've added more details.

Comment: Installing a module system-wide shouldn't have worked without `sudo`. What command did you use to install the module?

Comment: @VictorSergienko  I used `pip3 install module_name`.

Comment: @TomShanks it's possible you installed the library in your user's python site-packages instead of the system, since you managed to install it without using `sudo`. Run `pip3 show module_name`, what is the Location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how `pip install` without `sudo` could have worked.

What I see: scripts run on startup from cron or [/etc/profile](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63034/using-etc-profile-over-home-pi-profile) are run under root, not under `pi` user. Thus, they don't have the same `$PATH`, `$PYTHONPATH` and other environment variable values that you have in your user's shell.

As `pip install` managed to run without `sudo`, I suspect that you installed your module into a user-specific directory, which is not a part of `root`'s Python environment.

Replacing the `/etc/profile` line with `sudo -u pi python3 script.py` may help.

Whatever it is, it's the difference that is already in the Python environment. Waiting for 10s "for whatever to come up" will not help it.

Comment: I probably used `sudo` I just don't remember.

Comment: This `sudo -u pi python3 script.py`  worked ! ! ! God bless you mate !

Comment: Would you share with me what the `-u` is for there ? It's an optional parameter but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: In the core of Linux magic lies a tome of wisdom: the `man` command. Type `man sudo` in the shell and find the ancient (indeed, about half a century old) knowledge. Or just look it up online: https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Answer (score -1):

1 - Download anaconda: https://www.anaconda.com/download/

2 - Create an environment in conda: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

3 - Activate that environment

4 - `conda  install` or `pip3 install` your package

It *should* just work.

Comment: I was hoping this could be done without having to fiddle around with another library.

Comment: I really encourage you to explore anaconda as it solves more problems for you than you may realize right now.